# How to give an abstract parameter object to a method of an abstract class?

Tags: java, reflection, abstract-class

How can I give a parameter to a method using Javas Reflection API?

The idea is to have many *param* classes (POJOs) and each of them has its own
*service* class. The *service* class has a method "save" to persist a *param* object.

Class *FileImporter* should just use params and services by their name.

Here is a code snippet with lots of simplifications.

```
class Param extends AbstractParam {
... class body ...
}

abstract class BaseService {
    abstract void save(AbstractParam p);
}

class Service extends BaseService {
    ConcreteParam save(ConcreteParam param) {
        ... method body. EntityManager omitted ... }
}

class FileImporter {
    void importJson(String serviceName, String paramName, Map<String,Object> jsonMap ) {
            //--- Build service object
            Class<AbstractService> serviceClass =
                    (Class<AbstractService>) Class.forName( serviceName );
            Constructor<?> ctor =
                    serviceClass.getConstructor( (Class<?>[]) null );
            AbstractService service = (AbstractService) ctor.newInstance();

            //--- Build parameter constructor for reuse
            Class<AbstractParameter> paramClass =
                (Class<AbstractParameter>) Class.forName( paramName );
            paramConstructor = paramClass .getConstructor( (Class<?>[]) null );
            
            //--- Build parameter and fill from map
            AbstractParameter param = paramConstructor.newInstance();
            BeanHelper.populate( param, entityMap ); // populates param recursively
            param = service.save( param );
}
```

This approach ends with compiler error "method 'save' is not applicable for arguments".

Comment: *"method 'save' is not applicable for arguments".* - this is because you declare `service` as `AbstractService service = (AbstractService) ctor.newInstance();` but `save` is a method on `Service` not `AbstractService`.

Comment: I have updated the example but the compiler is still not able to resolve the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Only solution I have found is to use reflection because the compiler cannot validate types. Use like this:

```
//--- Obtain save method from service class
Method method = serviceClass.getDeclaredMethod( "save", Class<AbstractParameter>);

//--- Invoke method on service object
method.invoke( serviceObject, param );
```